# How to use rosservice call with correct parameter form?

Tags: ros, rosservice, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using Roscopter package and want to send some waypoints to my copter.

The `/waypoint` is a service I can find using `rosservice list`

they type of `/waypoint` is `roscopter/SendWaypoint` I use `rossrv show` to check the type format:

```
roscopter/Waypoint waypoint
  uint8 TYPE_NAV=1
  uint8 TYPE_CONDITION_YAW=2
  uint8 TYPE_CONDITION_CHANGE_ALT=3
  uint8 TYPE_TAKEOFF=4
  int32 latitude
  int32 longitude
  int32 altitude
  uint16 pos_acc
  uint8 speed_to
  uint16 hold_time
  int32 yaw_from
  int32 pan_angle
  int32 tilt_angle
  uint8 waypoint_type
---
bool result
```

then I run the command:
`rosservice call /waypoint 15 22 0 40 0 30 3 0 0 0`

I put 10 arguments for 10 parameters but got the error:

```
ERROR: Incompatible arguments to call service:
Too many arguments:
 * Given: [15, 22, 0, 40, 0, 30, 3, 0, 0, 0]
 * Expected: ['waypoint']
Provided arguments are:
 * 15 (type int)
 * 22 (type int)
 * 0 (type int)
 * 40 (type int)
 * 0 (type int)
 * 30 (type int)
 * 3 (type int)
 * 0 (type int)
 * 0 (type int)
 * 0 (type int)

Service arguments are: [waypoint.latitude waypoint.longitude waypoint.altitude waypoint.pos_acc waypoint.speed_to waypoint.hold_time waypoint.yaw_from waypoint.pan_angle waypoint.tilt_angle waypoint.waypoint_type]
```

the content of waypoint.msg

```
# latitude and longitude given in decimal degrees (* 10^7)
int32 latitude
int32 longitude

# height in mm
int32 altitude

# posAcc given in mm
uint16 pos_acc

# max speed to travel to waypoint in % of 100
uint8 speed_to

# time to stay at waypoint in ms
uint16 hold_time

# yawFrom angle given in degrees (* 1000)
int32 yaw_from

# camera pan and tilt angles during waypoint travel given in degrees (* 1000)
int32 pan_angle
int32 tilt_angle

# Type of Waypoint
uint8 waypoint_type

uint8 TYPE_NAV = 1
uint8 TYPE_CONDITION_YAW = 2
uint8 TYPE_CONDITION_CHANGE_ALT = 3
uint8 TYPE_TAKEOFF = 4
```

Then I used the following format but there is still an error:

```
>rosservice call /waypoint "{waypoint.latitude: 15, waypoint.longitude: 22, waypoint.speedTo: 0, waypoint.altitude: 40, waypoint.hold_time: 0, waypoint.yaw_from: 30, waypoint.pos_acc: 3, waypoint.pan_angle: 0,waypoint.tilt_angle: 0,waypoint_type: 1}"

ERROR: Incompatible arguments to call service:
No field name [waypoint.longitude]
Provided arguments are:
 * {'waypoint.longitude': 22, 'waypoint.speedTo': 0, 'waypoint.altitude': 40, 'waypoint.tilt_angle': 0, 'waypoint.pan_angle': 0, 'waypoint.latitude': 15, 'waypoint.hold_time': 0, 'waypoint.yaw_from': 30, 'waypoint_type': 1, 'waypoint.pos_acc': 3} (type dict)

Service arguments are: [waypoint.latitude waypoint.longitude waypoint.altitude waypoint.pos_acc waypoint.speed_to waypoint.hold_time waypoint.yaw_from waypoint.pan_angle waypoint.tilt_angle waypoint.waypoint_type]
```

So I think I should send all the data in one group as the type `waypoint`, but I don't know what to do...

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173448/how-to-use-rosservice-call-with-correct-parameter-form?/) by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on ROS Answers with karma: 279 on 2014-06-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just hit tab after typing `rosservice call /waypoint` and your shell will present you an empty message body which you can fill with values.

If this does not work try `rosservice call /waypoint roscopter/SendWaypoint` and then tab.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-07-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on 2014-07-03**:
Thanks but after I entered tab it became `rosservice call /waypoint Usage: rosservice type /service` followed by an error `rosservice: error: service must be specified`

**Comment by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on 2014-07-03**:
well, nothing showed up this time...

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-06-27**:
My shell doesn't show anything but an error. `Usage: rosservice call /service [args...]`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

well, I think I find the answer, accidently

I'm using zsh instead of bash, I tried once using format

`rosservice call /waypoint [15,22,0,40,0,30,3,0,0,1]`

but the return is

```
zsh: no matches found: [15,22,0,40,0,30,3,0,0,1]
```

I changed into bash just know and tried the same command, but there is no error:

```
>rosservice call /waypoint [15,22,0,40,0,30,3,0,0,1]
result: False
```

then I think that is the correct form and there is sth wrong with my zsh,

after google I add an alias in my .zshrc `alias rosservice='noglob rosservice'`  and then I got the same result in zsh `return false`

so the format problem is solved out, but now I need to find out why it return false....

but I'm still wondering is there exist a more readable format like what I use in the question?

Because I think putting every argument inside [] without telling which is which is not quite user-friendly

---

Originally posted by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) with karma: 279 on 2014-07-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-07-03**:
Please always add some information about your system. Most ROS users use Ubuntu and Bash, so this is assumed if nothing else is mentioned.

**Comment by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on 2014-07-03**:
@BennyRe thanks for your suggestion, I will add more detail in my future asking

**Comment by [AllieCat_Duncan](https://answers.ros.org/users/20329/alliecat_duncan/) on 2014-09-28**:
@lanyusea Did you have any luck with rosservice call /waypoint. I am also getting a "result: False" and can't figure out why...

**Comment by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on 2019-06-27**:
@AllieCat_Duncan really old question. I remember I change my shell from Zsh to Bash, then it works.